# Sum Individual Column Values Across Rows in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, sum, dax, powerpivot

Using PowerPivot, I would like to sum data across the rows. (I would like to do this all in PowerPivot)

For example:

Current Table:

[image: Current Table]

Desired Table:

[image: Desired Table]

Comment: Does the first picture illustrate the layout of your raw data, or of the PivotTable you created based on that raw data?

Comment: @jeffreyweir the Current Table represents the raw data.  The Desired table represents what I would like the raw table to look like in  Powerpivot (minus Level 1,2 headings of course)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PowerPivot to do this...you just need to 'unpivot' your source data **before** you make a 'traditional' PivotTable out of it.

Currently your raw data is in a crosstabulated layout. PivotTables don't like crosstabs...they need unpivoted flat files, so that they can do this kind of summation.

To unpivot your data, see one of the following links:

- Use PowerQuery aka "Get and Transform". This is built in to Excel
  2016 and available as a free add-in from Microsoft for 2010/2013.
  Google PowerQuery Unpivot and you will turn up hundreds of tutorials,
  such as this one from my good pal Chandoo
  https://chandoo.org/wp/2015/09/29/unpivot-data-with-power-query/
- Use VBA. Google Unpivot VBA and turn up hundreds of results,
  including this blazingly fast code I posted some time back:
  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/
  (Look for the code under the —Update 26 November 2013— heading.)
- Use the DoubleClick extraction trick. See
  http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/transposing-a-dataset-with-a-pivottable/

My money is on PowerQuery...especially given you have nested categories. Check out Ken Puls' article at https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2017/10/30/unpivoting-subcategories/ on how to accomplish this (and check out his book M is for Data Monkeys too...it's excellent)

The layout you need is like this:

[image]

...and then you can use a 'normal' PivotTable to show this:

[image]

Comment: I know I don't need powerpivot and my data is not currently pivoted.  This is data I'm pulling from Access via powerpivot.  I need a calculated column/measure in order to sum up the levels.  I would like to do this all in powerpivot for easy 1 button refresh.

Comment: Can't you just change your Access SQL query to unpivot the data? How are you importing the data into Excel?

Comment: as I said before, I am importing the data into excel via PowerPivot and again, my data is not pivoted.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? In some versions there are two ways to pull data into PowerPivot...using the direct 'legacy' Access connector, or using PowerQuery. Using PowerQuery to pull data into PowerPivot is considered best, because you can 'shape' the data before pulling it into the PowerPivot 'data modelling' engine. In short, while some things can be done in either PP OR PQ, this is one of the cases where it's best done in PQ.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Jeff

Comment: That's not to say you can't do this in PP. But you'd have to write measures for each and every product that you want to show in your PivotTable, and again for the totals. Which gets pretty tedious.

Comment: Note that because you have nested categories, then out of the options I listed in my answer, PowerQuery is the way to go. As per my edit, check out https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2017/10/30/unpivoting-subcategories/

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you don't need any pivot table for this. You could use SUMIF function and easily extract the information you need. Split the merged cells and that will become your criteria. Then, you add each ID which is at the level your looking. Suppose you have the top left corner at A1, you can use this :

```
Level 1 Level 1 Level 2 Level 2 Level 2 Level 1 Level 2
ID  Prod 1  Prod 2  Prod 3  Prod 4  Prod 5      
1   7   1   5   9   6   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&G$1,$B3:$F3)   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&H$1,$B3:$F3)
2   6   4   6   2   8   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&G$1,$B4:$F4)   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&H$1,$B4:$F4)
3   2   4   2   3   8   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&G$1,$B5:$F5)   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&H$1,$B5:$F5)
4   1   8   2   1   6   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&G$1,$B6:$F6)   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&H$1,$B6:$F6)
5   4   3   4   1   7   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&G$1,$B7:$F7)   =SUMIF($B$1:$F$1,"="&H$1,$B7:$F7)
```

Explaining the formula, you have as first argument the range in which the criteria will be checked. Here, it is your level. The second argument corresponds to the level you wish to add. Therefore, the top right cells (`G1` -> `Level 1`, `H1` -> `Level 2`) are the criteria; what should the range criteria be equal to in order to be summed. Last, it's the range that should be added. We take the row corresponding to the ID (For `ID 1`, it's row 3, `ID 2`, it's row 4, etc.). than will give your expected results.

Comment: I know I don't need powerpivot and my data is not currently pivoted.  This is data I'm pulling from Access via powerpivot.  I need a calculated column/measure in order to sum up the levels.  Well aware of SUMIFS.  As I said I would like a way to do this in powerpivot.  Thanks for the suggestion.